# Tratamiento formal plural en Argentina: "vosotros" versus "ustedes"

Tags: argentina, formalidad, voseo, ustedeo

En Argentina es común el uso de *ustedes* para referirse a un grupo de personas no formalmente. ¿Pero entonces *vosotros* sería formal? Hasta donde tengo entendido es demasiado formal (y arcaico), es decir, que no se usaría como plural de 'usted'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Vosotros* no se emplea en Argentina, ni siquiera de manera formal. Hace unos cuantos años se lo podía oír aún, junto con las formas posesivas (*vuestro*, *vuestra*, y sus plurales) y las formas verbales de la segunda persona del plural, en la liturgia católica, pero incluso los misales católicos hace tiempo que adoptaron la forma latinoamericana "estándar" con *ustedes* (aunque siguen usando el *tú* y no el *vos* para la forma singular).

No existe una manera concisa de indicar un contraste entre formalidad e informalidad en el dialecto rioplatense en la segunda persona del plural; *ustedes* es neutro en cuanto a eso. Vale decir: en singular se dice *vos* informalmente y *usted* formalmente; en plural, sin importar el registro, se usa *ustedes*. Nadie se enojará si se lo nombra de esta manera, por mucha formalidad que exija la ocasión.

En ciertos contextos se puede recurrir a reemplazar el pronombre por alguna perífrasis que denote formalidad, como *los señores* o *las señoras*, pero no es algo que uno tenga ocasión de escuchar con frecuencia y suena como algo que diría un subordinado (un sirviente, un camarero, un mayordomo) a un grupo de dignatarios. En Argentina la excesiva formalidad al hablar está mal vista en general.

Comment: Coincido con pablodf76. Existe una tendencia, errónea e inconsistente, a utilizar "vuestro/a/s" en la correspondencia comercial que busca eliminar la ambigüedad del "su". Estoy de acuerdo en que el uso de "los señores" es inusual y propio de un subalterno. Para ser muy formal, se puede usar el vocativo "señores": Señores, ustedes sabrán disculpar... / Ustedes sabrán disculpar, señores, ...