# ¿Cómo se dice "ustedes" en un manera informal?

Tags: pronombres, formalidad, ustedeo

How exactly would one say *ustedes* in an informal way? I'm not talking about vosotros, since it is only used in Spain.

Comment: This Q&A might be helpful https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/tratamiento-formal-plural-en-argentina-vosotros-versus-ustedes

Comment: The Q&A that @mdewey indicates is about Argentina, but I think the answer holds in general. I'll be waiting to see if someone has something to add about other dialects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for the second person **plural** actually there are not other pronouns different to *ustedes* and *vosotros* and *vosotros* is not used in many places outside Spain then *ustedes* is used both for formal and informal conversations.

For the **singular** there are other forms like «tu», «vos» and «usted» that are used differently for formal or informal situations but that does not happen for the plural where only «ustedes» is used.

As already said in [@pablod76's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/tratamiento-formal-plural-en-argentina-vosotros-versus-ustedes) there are other ways to refer to groups of people like «los señores» that may be more formal but when using the pronoun there is no problem in using *ustedes* either in formal or informal conversations because there is no other way.

The question being about the informal use, the answer would be there is no special way of using *ustedes* but if instead the situation requieres to show respect and be formal then you should show that by adding other things tu your sentence. i.e *"Respetuosamente les pido a ustedes..."* or *"ustedes me disculparán..."*

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I don't get why there's no form of tu for ustedes, but i guess that's just spanish being weird.

Comment: @PinruiHuang tú → vosotros; usted → ustedes. If vosotros is not an option, then ustedes must be used regardless of formality.